# Get call record by calling Microsoft Graph API(beta)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am new to Microsoft Graph API, my ultimate goal is to create a Power BI report to show Microsoft Teams call related matrix.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) i can see the HTTP sample (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/{id}). There are couple of things that are not clear in the documentation.

1. Where can i get the call *id* to use in the sample request.
2. *CallRecords.Read.All* permission is required to get call data, where do i need to set this permission and what is the process.

Comment: did you get any success with this.  I have set the permission but still cant get this working.

Answer (score 2):

I can help with item 2. Your CallRecords.Read.All permission needs to be added for  GraphAPI in the API Permissions in AzureAD (https://aad.portal.azure.com/).

[image: Add permission in the API Permission in AzureAD]

But I'm probably trying to do the same as you. And also need to figure out how to get the Call Id.
Laurence

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Where can i get the call id to use in the sample request.

You can get the call id from 2 places:

1. From Office365->Admin->Teams->Search User->Call History->Select a call history

The call id is in your browser address bar, for example https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/users/xxxxxxxx/calls-session/***e57d1123-af1c-4d07-8153-c38a1320e3b2***

2. Create a [callRecord subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

O365 sends HTTP POST to your endpoint each time a call is completed.  The payload will contain the call id.